# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'absolute_links'

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://www.walmart.com/search?q=70+inch+tv&page=2&affinityOverride=default'

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1,timeout=20)
product = r.html.find('div.mb1.ph1.pa0-xl.bb.b--near-white.w-25')



productinfo = []
for item in product.absolute_links:
    # ra = s.get(item)
    # name = ra.html.find('h1',first=True).text
    products = {
        'link' :item,

    }

    productinfo.append(products)

print(productinfo)
print(len(productinfo))
```

Output

```
for item in product.absolute_links:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'absolute_links'
```

I want to get link of  every product than scrape some data from this website by requests-html library , but i'm getting attribute error.please help me.chack  the website html

Comment: When I run your code, `product` is an empty list. It looks like you need to log in, or at least solve a captcha first.

Comment: how to select tag in requests-html ?

Comment: It's not about selecting a tag. The tag doesn't exist in the returned HTML because you need to log in to the site first. Examine the returned HTML and see for yourself.

Comment: so that's mean's I have to use selenium. But can  I solve captcha and logging via requests-html library? I'm not super familiar with requests-html library

Answer (score 0):

> But can I solve captcha and logging via requests-html library? I'm not super familiar with requests-html library

Neither am I, but you can paste the request from your browser to https://curlconverter.com/ (they also [have instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgrHp.png) on how to copy the request) and they'll convert it to python code for a request with headers and cookies that you can then paste into your code. The last line of their code will be *`response = requests.get(.....`*, but you can replace it with *`r = s.get(...`* so that your code can still use `requests_html` methods like `.html.render` and `.absolute_links` (`requests` doesn't parse the HTML).

Just keep in mind that the **cookies will expire**, likely within a few hours, and that you'll have to copy them from your browser again by then if you want to keep scraping this way.

---

> ```py
> for item in product.absolute_links: 
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'absolute_links'
> ```

You can only apply `.absolute_links` to an *element* and [`.find`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.Element.find) returns a *list* of elements (unless you specify `first=True`). Also `.absolute_links` returns a [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) of links [even when that set only contains one link], so you need to either loop through them or convert to list and access it through indexing to get at the link/s.

```py
product = r.html.find('div.mb1.ph1.pa0-xl.bb.b--near-white.w-25')

productinfo = []
for prod in product:
    item = prod.absolute_links # get product link/s
    # ra = s.get(list(item)[0]) # go to first product link
    # name = ra.html.find('h1',first=True).text
    products = {'link' :item, }
    productinfo.append(products)
```

or, to absolutely ensure that you're looping through a *unique* urls,

```py
product = r.html.find('div.mb1.ph1.pa0-xl.bb.b--near-white.w-25')
prodUrls = set().union(*[d.absolute_links for d in product]) # combine all sets of product links

productinfo = []
for item in prodUrls:
    # ra = s.get(item) 
    # name = ra.html.find('h1',first=True).text
    products = {'link' :item, }
    productinfo.append(products)
```

---

Btw, if it doesn't *find* any products, then ofc you won't get any links even if the error goes away, so add a line to print the request status (in case something went wrong there) as well as how many products and links were extracted.

```py
print(r.status_code, r.reason, f' - {len(product)} products and {len(prodUrls)} product links from', r.url)
```